# Error running Truffle migrate

Tags: truffle, testrpc

Does anyone know why the below occur.

Command: `truffle migrate --reset`

```
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid JUMP at 77d169e30e9d6e6f0835f612842170d5645160866ff64a47ea0dcca21134db9e/fef606469abd03c7e72bf6cbf8fe9816506af31b:56
at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/errors.js:35:16)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/ether-pudding/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/requestmanager.js:86:36
    at request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/web3/lib/web3/httpprovider.js:114:13)
    at dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:591:25)
    at setState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:610:14)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/node_modules/xmlhttprequest/lib/XMLHttpRequest.js:447:13)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:974:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:122:9)
```

Contract: https://gist.github.com/ViswanathL/9289c8e00d370d19d2b4534fa743a342

Comment: Which version of truffle are your using (execute `truffle version`). Also could you send the content of your truffle.js.

Comment: @gjeanmart Truffle v2.1.1

Comment: This could usually occur when the gas required for execution is larger than the default limit. This limit can be raised in truffle.js within the rpc object, by setting gas and gasPrice to new upper limits

Comment: Can occur if the contract constructor fails, for example, a required value wasn't passed in so it decided to throw. It may be possible to spot an issue if you post the contract source and migration scripts.

Comment: @RobHitchens you were right. It was due to error in constructor. Can't we add `verifiers[0] = msg.sender;` in constructor ? `verifiers` is `address[]`

Comment: @ViswanathLekshmanan. Sure. You can do things like that. if you're having trouble getting it to happen post your contract in a question edit and I'll help you sort it out.

Comment: @RobHitchens Updated the contract code in gits. Please check

Comment: `invalid JUMP` generally happens when something wrong with the EVM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two events in two verify functions, `onMamaVerified(`... and `onAuthorVerified(` and these don't match event Log(string) so it doesn't compile.

After the successful compile, the constructor was walking off the end the array in `verifiers[0]` because row zero isn't addressable in an empty array. I changed it to `verifiers.push(msg.sender)` for an append. The constructor is happy now.

I can't say I considered any more than getting it to compile and deploy. Dropped the edited code in your gist.

Hope it helps.

p.s. I changed the Author references to Authorized to make it easier for me to think about it.